# Overriding HTML and CSS class

Tags: html, css, squarespace

I have a Squarespace site that has a `div` that has `align-center-vert` and I was trying to override it to `align-top-vert` but can't figure out how to do it.

I have been trying to inject code on Squarespace to override the class like so:

```
<style>
  .align-center-vert {
    position: top!important;
  }
</style>
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

The full `div` doesnt have an ID either which makes it hard.

```
<div class="sqs-slice-group group-copy align-center-vert full-width">
      <div class="sqs-slice" data-slice-type="heading" data-slice-id="5b018c461ae6cf341dcc163e" data-content-empty="true"></div>
      <div class="sqs-slice" data-slice-type="body" data-slice-id="5b018c461ae6cf341dcc163f" data-content-empty="true"></div>
      <div class="responsive-wrapper actions" style="display: inline-block;">
        <div class="sqs-slice" data-slice-type="custom-form" data-content-empty="true"></div><div class="sqs-slice yui3-widget sqs-slice-navigation sqs-slice-navigation-content sqs-slice-navigation-focused" data-slice-type="navigation" data-compound-type="action" data-slice-id="5b018c461ae6cf341dcc1642" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1526841597381_309"><ul id="yui_3_17_2_1_1526841597381_382"><li id="yui_3_17_2_1_1526841597381_381"><a href="/archive" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1526841597381_380">Archive</a></li><li><a href="/shop">Shop</a></li></ul></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `position: top` setting in CSS. If you want to override a `vertical-align` setting, use `vertical-align: top`

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Also when I inspect element and change it to align-top-vert it changes to aligning top.